# how to select an entire column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a data sheet similar to excel with columns and rows and a buttons to add rows and column if needed I want to make a cell or div disabled (for read-only) that display the summation of numbers inside cells in a specific column, the problem is how I select that column and every newly added cell to that column

here is the code of the datasheet

```
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="search">
    <button class="table_btn" id="addrow">
      Add Row
    </button>
    <button class="table_btn" id="addcol">
      Add Column
    </button>
    <button class="table_btn" id="sav">
      Save
    </button>
    <button class="table_btn" id="edi">
      Edit
    </button>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-box" />
  </div>
  <table
    class="table table-striped table-dark table-hover table-bordered"
    id="mtable"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="tableTd" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/georgesteven1/5dsn7ouc/22/

Comment: What do you refer to with "select that column and every newly added cell to that column" ?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you are looking for a selector for all elements in a certain column. If so you can use the ":nth-child(n)" CSS selector.
Let's say you need to select the second column:

```
   $("tr td:nth-child(2)").addClass("selected");
```

Hope it helps.